# How do you disable Auto Updates for Crystal Reports 2013?

Tags: crystal-reports

Our network configuration on the machine where we run Crystal Reports 2013 changed and it can no longer access the internet.  So, when we launch Crystal Reports 2013, the application hangs on startup and the crw32.exe process needs to be killed from task manager.  How can we prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The setting is stored in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Crystal Reports\CheckForUpdates`.  Look for a DWORD key called `DisableOnStartUp`.  Create it if missing.  Set the value to 1.  Problem solved.